# Unit-testing mouse event handlers

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, components

When unit-testing a component, the following question occured to me:

There are a number of mouse-related event handlers. I see two possibilties to test these handlers:

1. Simulate mouse events using Windows API calls.
2. Use the [protected hack](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/l/aa082603a.htm) to access protected event handlers and call them directly.

I know that unit testing is normally restricted to the interface of a class (which also means that tests don't have to be changed when class internals change), but is this scenario worth an exception?

How do you usually handle mouse events when unit-testing components?

Comment: 1. is better to find timing-related problems, such as cases where `TActionManager.OnUpdate` code has not executed yet and some UI elements are not in their intended state. Fast-clicking/typing users can (and will) run into these problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I think you need an architectural change to facilitate automated user interface testing. Reasons why are well formulated in this article: http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/01/04/ui-test-automation-tools-are-snake-oil

The Delphi Magazine once had an interesting article on automated testing of user interfaces from code (without a specific gui testing tool that is). Taking a bit longer to find than I expected and may not be available online. Will update my answer when/if I find it.

The article is "Creating Easily Testable User Interfaces" by Julian Bucknall (DevExpress) and was published in issue 120 of "The Delphi Magazine". Unfortunately the article is no longer online. You would have to buy the total collection of The Delphi Magazine: a 1 GB USB stick with all issues and all codes ever published in The Delphi Magazine. Well worth the 36 GBP! (And no, I do not get a commission).

Comment: Please note that the question is specifically about the mouse event of a visual component and the logic executed from this handlers. It's not about testing business logic.

Comment: The Delphi Magazine article I mention isn't about testing business logic either, it is about separating your forms and events from the logic that controls them so you can write tests that "perform" a mouse click and check that the appropriate controls and actions have been enabled/made visible/etc. It is all about testing the user interface, not the business logic.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you are supposed to write your code in a way you can test it, so you test the methods you call by the mouseevent without simulating the mouse event.

In order to do that you need a good separated GUI and logical middleware.

Can you maby provide some Code or more information on the funcions you call on the mousevents in your app.

Comment: The mouse events basically deal with selection in the component. But even if I reduce the event handlers to a bare minimum, I won't expose the methods called from there in the public interface. So I will have to call protected methods anyway or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: This doesn't help. So what if you have separated your GUI and your middleware? Your GUI code still exists, still needs to run, and still needs to do the right thing. This is a general question about GUI testing.

Comment: @David: ur right, GUI has to be tested but not with UT, as u mentioned there are other tools for this job. And separating GUI and MW is the right way to separate functionality from UI, well maby not in this special case where we talk about a visual component but in general.

Comment: @Smasher: if you really need to you still can derive a new class of your component in the same unit where you have your test, so you can access protected methods. would this be an accepted solution for your problem?

Comment: @O.D That's what Smasher means by the "protected hack".

Comment: Ouch! That Hurts! :) didnt notice it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for some automated GUI testing.  You could try [Test Complete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/) from Smart Bear, for example.

DUnit does offer some basic GUI testing facilities (in the GUITesting unit) but I don't think it may not be comprehensive enough for your needs.

Comment: we already use Test Complete for black box testing, but I tried to complement these tests with some unit tests. In your opinion, are there any reasons not to use my second suggestion?

Comment: @Smasher I'd normally view UI testing, if I understand your needs correctly, as something best suited for integration tests rather than unit tests. Does your "black box testing", as you describe it, not cover these event handlers?

Comment: It probably does, but is something that is not under my direct control, so I can't run it as a regression test for example. And I would have to merge the coverage of both methods to see what I am really covering.